# Which date format to use with inputs for the Quick Actions REST API? (INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD)

Tags: rest-api, api, error, date, quickaction

I'm receiving the error `INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD` when invoking a custom sobject quick action to create a record and its payload specifies a `Date` or `DateTime` field as an input value.

For example, to create an opportunity record and specify its `CloseDate`.

---

I'm using the SObject Quick Actions API as documented in the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_quickactions.htm) and [Actions Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_intro_invoking.htm).

[image: workbench rest explorer]

```
[ {
  "actionName" : "Account.Custom_Create_Oppty",
  "errors" : [ {
    "statusCode" : "INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD",
    "message" : "Close Date: value not of required type: 2019-11-26",
    "fields" : [ "CloseDate" ]
  } ],
  "isSuccess" : false,
  "outputValues" : null
} ]
```

I'm very confused because I've tried many variations of ISO8601 date formats with no luck.

Thanks

---

## Steps to Reproduce

To reproduce the issue, in Setup go to the Account object and create a new action to create a related opportunity (or other object with a date field).

My action simply has the `Name` and `Close Date` fields on its layout:

[image: quick action layout]

And two predefined field values for the required `Stage` and `Amount` fields:

[image: quick action details]

From here, create an account record in your org then use Workbench or another tool to invoke the Actions REST API.

[image: workbench rest explorer]

Comment: Have you tried without quotes surrounding the dates?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I haven’t tried without quotes around the date, but the data payload is JSON so I don’t think it would be valid as to my knowledge there isn’t a date-type for JSON other than ISO8601 formatted strings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format/15952652#15952652

Comment: I see, well, maybe worth trying to but most likely you are correct. I also think would be weird if it works.

Comment: Try 2019-11-29T12:34:56. When I built this tool for Aura (https://github.com/eltoroit/ETLC_ApexBridge) I passed the dates / date-times as JSON. 

Send from JS: new date.toJSON();
Receive with Apex: DateTime.valueOf(strDate);

I used date-time for both dates and date-times, one reason was that it calculates to GTM in the client and then you do not need to worry about the user's timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Andres. I’ve also tried those formats and formats documented at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_date_format.htm with no luck. I’m thinking this may be a bug with the API not handling the date strings properly. 

I’d love to know if other people are seeing same results when they try this.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Support has logged a bug internally. For reference, the work item is **W-6965020**.

At the time of posting, I don't believe a "known issue" document has been issued.